# Joomla Upgrade Error

Tags: joomla

I am newbie to Joomla.

I upgraded joomla site. But I am getting this error

Warning: strstr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/nirankar/public_html/intranet/libraries/joomla/cache/controller/callback.php on line 63

Warning: strstr() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/nirankar/public_html/intranet/libraries/joomla/cache/controller/callback.php on line 69

Fatal error: Call to undefined method JApplicationAdministrator::isClient() in /home/nirankar/public_html/intranet/administrator/components/com_login/models/login.php on line 148

Please help me to overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

The `libraries/joomla/cache` folder doesn't exist in Joomla 3.8. You will need to rename your current `libraries` folder and copy a fresh one from a Joomla 3.8 zip file. See [here](https://www.itoctopus.com/call-to-undefined-method-japplicationsiteisclient-when-updating-to-joomla-3-8) for a similar error.

The problem that you're having is very common when the update is done manually by overwriting the Joomla files and then "repairing" the database.

Comment: I have tried this solution but still same error I am getting.

Comment: Are you sure you renamed the old libraries folder and changed it with the one from Joomla 3.8? This should fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah I have tried this solution, but no improvement